# When button is clicked how to get the text from the textbox immediately above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code like:

```
<input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
<input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
```

There is a button click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {

            var findpersonbutton = $(this);

            var searchbox = $(this).closest('.searchpersontxtbox');
            alert(show the searchbox text here);

        });
    });
```

So when the button is clicked I'm trying to get the text in the searchbox and alert it to the screen.

One point to note is that there could be multiple searchboxes on the page with 'searchpersontxtbox' class.

So I'm wanting to get the text from the textbox that is right above the button.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Err… the button is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) works. Without seeing the rest of your markup, one way to do this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.findpersonbtn').click(function () {
        var findpersonbutton = $(this)
            , searchbox = $(this).prev();

        alert(searchbox.val());
    });
});
```

You can use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the element right above the clicked `.findpersonbtn`.

Comment: Perhaps $(this).prev('.searchpersontxtbox'); just to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

I think hes looking for something relative... like this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.findpersonbtn ').click(function () {
     var findpersonbutton = $(this);

//do relative search here...
     var searchbox = findpersonbutton.parent().find('.searchpersontxtbox');
     alert(searchbox.val());

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    alert(button);
    }
});
```

something like that? search for getting textarea value with jQuery, then apply that method in a variable and alert out it's text. should work?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out `.previousSibling()`, which should return the previous input.

http://jsfiddle.net/TbYup/